# Spark 2.1.1: How to bind the variables to Structured Streaming query

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, spark-structured-streaming

I want to use the variables for selecting the entries between the range of two variable values. My SQL query is `String sql = "Select count(*) FROM Records WHERE event_time <= UPPERTIME('1') AND event_time >= LOWERTIME('1')";`. In this query `UPPERTIME('1')` and `LOWERTIME('1')` are UDF and there definitions are

```java
    spark.udf().register("LOWERTIME",  new UDF1 < String, String > () {
         @Override public String call(String lowertime) {
             System.out.println("lowerTime="+lowerTime.toString());
             return lowerTime.toString();
             }
            }, DataTypes.StringType);


 spark.udf().register("UPPERTIME",  new UDF1 < String, String > () {
         @Override public String call(String uppertime) {
             System.out.println("upperTime="+upperTime.toString());
              return upperTime.toString();
             }
            }, DataTypes.StringType);
```

The argument passed to UDF is dummy and I am actually returning the global variable 'upperTime and lowerTime'.

When I run the above query, it shows count for all the entries in table, but according to condition it should show the count corresponding to the number of entries fall within the given range. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you changes these global variables in Driver and executors don't see the changes. An executor process is usually on a different node, and of cause it cannot access a normal variable in another process in another node.

Generally, using global variables in Spark is a bad idea. Spark provides [broadcast variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) to share variables between executors and driver.

Comment: Thanks @zsxwing, But the variable that I want to bind with my SQL query are not read-only, instead I want to increment them by some constant value after a specific condition has been met.

Comment: I don't think you can broadcast your changes during a Spark job. In addition, it seems you assume the order of processing data? That's usually wrong.